# How to synchronize data between two tables in different databases (MYSQL) running in different servers

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 different mysql database (OLD and NEW) running in different servers. OLD Database  has around 10 tables out of which i want to synchronize 3 tables database NEW. So if any addition/deletion/updation happens on those 3 tables then those entries should be updated on database NEW. 
I have created the NEW database using the mysql dump.
But I want to add a cron job which could run every 1 hour to sync the 3 tables.

I want to write a script which would keep track of last synced data using timestamps and then sync the data from OLD to NEW. I do have connectivity between both the server but I'm unable to figure out the way to achieve this.

Any suggestions or links would be appreciated.

Comment: do you absolutely *have* to replicate the data?  Replicating data can have many bad things happen.

Comment: @Marshall Tigerus - which bad things have replication. its  standard in MySQL and work very fine.

Comment: yes. we want to move to new databases eventually. we have different applications reading and writing to OLD database. But in the interim we would like to setup a NEW database and ask applications to move one by one.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I'm more referring to copying data to multiple databases, not anything managed by the DBMS itself.  I've worked at too many companies where instead of accessing data from a central database, data was copied from database to database for accessibility.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, why don't any of you guys answer this dude's question? Sometimes we have to do this due to security restrictions / compliance / legacy systems.

There's some options I'll write here with pseudo code. Not sure how real-time your database is so this won't work in all cases.

## Requirements

For this to work the databases will have to be in the same server instance. If not, you will need to setup a federate storage engine to access the remote data. As another person stated, MySQL replication could still be useful in at least getting the data to the same server making the synchronization faster without the need to setup federated storage.
Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html

## Sync Timing

> You can synchronize on an `event` schedule

MySQL will allow you to create events on a specific schedule to perform your work (assuming you don't have any external job scheduling tools).

Hopefully you have a modified date of some sort, you can query once a day or tighter intervals on all the fields where `modified_at` >=  DATE_SUB(NOW( ),INTERVAL ? HOUR)

If you are able to add a column, you could create one called `synced_at` which would be a little more resistant to server clock differences. Then you can simply query where `synced_at` IS NULL or `synced_at` <= `modified_at`

> Alternatively, use triggers

MySQL supports BEFORE and AFTER triggers of INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE etc... you can use these to trigger your logic. Keep in mind you will take a little performance penalty for each transaction and this can easily overwhelm very active production servers.

There really isn't a huge difference between BEFORE and AFTER except that if you use the BEFORE style triggers you can throw a sqlstate to prevent the insert into the source table if it is important for both tables to be highly synchronized.

## Sync Logic

> The INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE pattern

This is pseudo code but...

```
# new and updated records
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
SELECT FROM source_table
JOIN target_table.id
WHERE target_table.id IS NULL or modified_at > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ..)

# deleted records
```

> TRIGGER AFTER INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE

Same as above only you are just manipulating one record at a time and you are mirroring the trigger statement. For example: an INSERT TRIGGER on the source table should just query INSERT on the target table.

> The nuclear DROP / CREATE / INSERT

Simple but not recommended for anything other than maybe a reporting database. Drop the entire table and rebuild it from the other records.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use the MySQL replication you can also the tools from Percona
pt-table-sync this tool can find out which row must be copy and which other to be deleted , or updated. But both schemas must be identical

[here is the Manual](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html)

Comment: I was looking for solution which I could code myself rather than depending on 3rd party tool which might screw up DB if not used properly. I don't want master-slave configuration. I would like to take data from OLD periodically from tables which I choose and copy them to NEW in a script which gets executed in cron

Comment: @sumajumd - it really a hard work to do that by script. you can do mysqldump ... oldDB | mysql -hxxxx newDB, but it dont remove table onthe new db